# Reveal the meaning of DBAPI error message dictionary keys

Tags: python, database, python-db-api

For a few months Ive been working with pg8000 and have noticed when it throws an error like dbapi.ProgrammingError, the message is followed by a dictionary with some keys and values.  Where can I find a reference to explain the meaning of the keys?

For example:
{'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '42703', 'M': 'column \"add\" does not exist', 'P': '57', 'F':'parse_relation.c', 'L': '3294', 'R': 'errorMissingColumn'}